# Spark - Error “A master URL must be set in your configuration” using Intellij IDEA

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka

When i am trying to hit the Spark streaming application using Intellij IDEA

**Env**

Spark core version 2.2.0
Intellij IDEA 2017.3.5 VERSION

Additional info :
Spark is running on Yarn mode.

**Getting Error :**

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at kafka_stream.kafka_stream.main(kafka_stream.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2509)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:901)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:901)
    at kafka_stream.InitSpark$class.$init$(InitSpark.scala:15)
    at kafka_stream.kafka_stream$.<init>(kafka_stream.scala:6)
    at kafka_stream.kafka_stream$.<clinit>(kafka_stream.scala)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Tried this**

```
  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("SparkStructStream")
    .master("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")
    //.master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
```

Still getting the same MASTER URL ERROR

Content of  build.sbt file

```
name := "KafkaSpark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka_2.11" % "1.6.3"
)

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.11
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.11.0.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.11.0.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % "0.11.0.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/connect-api
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "connect-api" % "0.11.0.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "4.0.0"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
resolvers += "central maven" at "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
```

Any help on it would be much appreciated ?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the parameter is not passed somehow. E.g. the spark is initialized somewhere earlier. Nevertheless you can try with the VM option `-Dspark.master=local[*]`, that pass the parameter to all places where it is not defined, so it should solve your problem. In the IntelliJ it's in `list of run config -> Edit Configurations... -> VM Options`

Answer (score -3):

Download `winutils.exe` and place the file in `c/hadoop/bin/winutil.exe`
Include below line under def main statement

```
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop")
```

and it works well.